# parseexact translate everything into january in powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime

as you can see below, no matter what date i put in there , it gets translated into January.

anyone has an idea please?
thank you very much!

```
    PS C:\Users\jy70606> [datetime]::ParseExact("20170519".trim(),'yyyymmdd',$null)


Thursday, January 19, 2017 12:05:00 AM



PS C:\Users\jy70606> [datetime]::ParseExact("20170219".trim(),'yyyymmdd',$null)


Thursday, January 19, 2017 12:02:00 AM


PS C:\Users\jy70606> [datetime]::ParseExact("20160119".trim(),'yyyymmdd',$null)


Tuesday, January 19, 2016 12:01:00 AM




PS C:\Users\jy70606>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mm` is minutes. Use `MM` for months - E.g:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact("20170219".trim(),'yyyyMMdd',$null)
```

[Check out this page on Formatting DateTime](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx), and [the Custom DateTime Format Strings page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.80).aspx)

<sub>**Related:** [Standard DateTime Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.80).aspx)</sub>